# error in a macro to return yellow rows

Tags: vba, excel

i have a macro to identify if a cell says "Pgto Proximo" and color the whole row if yes. There is a type mistmatch error and I can't figure out what is wrong. I would appreciate your help

```
Sub pintar_amarelo()

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 200 To 2 Step -1

        If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Pgto Proximo" Then

            Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

         Else

            Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

         End If

    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guesssing it is the Rows(i) reference.  just use the cell and select the entire row

```
Sub pintar_amarelo()

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 200 To 2 Step -1

        If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Pgto Proximo" Then

            Cells(i, 6).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

         Else

            Cells(i, 6).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

         End If

    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited from prior attempt at answering through code correction [for which I was incorrect**

Have you considered simply considered a conditional format?

Something like:

Select the entire workbook. Click Conditional Formatting -> New Rule.

```
=$F1="Pgto Proximo"
```

Then make that highlight yellow; this will impact the entire row; all other rows will be highlighted blank.

Comment: Rows returns a range object.  Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 does indeed work as long as i is a valid integer value.

Comment: @user7004  what line returns Type Mismatch?